# Объединить несколько ячеек столбца в один (SQL)

Tags: sql

У меня в SQL есть табличка типа как внизу.
Как можно для каждого уникального col1 получить список всех значений merging для него?
Т.е. в верхней ячейке merging хочу получить список [some, content, to, merge, above]
В питоне похожее делала через цикл, но тут даже не знаю как быть. Буду очень признательна за любые идеи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая у вас СУБД?

Comment: субд разработана внутри компании, но очень многофункциональная. если что под нее переделаю, были бы идеи как реализовать вообще)

Comment: Идеи: для MySQL - `GROUP_CONCAT` для Oracle `LISTAGG`. Основная идея вызвать нужную агрегирующую функцию и указать в запросе `GROUP BY col1`

Comment: *субд разработана внутри компании* Точно именно СУБД, а не интерфейс к какой-то стандартной СУБД?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нашла аналог, спасибо!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postgres, mssql (c 2017)

```
SELECT col1, STRING_AGG(merging, ',') AS group_merging 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY col1;
```

oracle

```
SELECT col1, LISTAGG(merging, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS group_merging 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY col1;
```

MySQL

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(merging SEPARATOR ',')
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col1;
```